# crash when handle responsed JSON data in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new for swift , because of lack in experience to handle json data, I can't solve this :

```
    /*response handler*/
    var response : NSURLResponse? = nil
    var error : NSError? = nil
    let responseData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)
    println(responseData)
    if (responseData == nil ){
        println("error message")
    } else {
        var encodedResponsedData:NSString = NSString(data:responseData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println(encodedResponsedData);

        let jsonData : NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary


        println(jsonData["error"])
    }
```

in

```
    println(encodedResponsedData);
```

step it returns

> {"success":1,"error":"No error message","user_id": -1 }

however `

> let jsonData : NSDictionary =
>   NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData!,
>   options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary

in this step the app crashed and returns

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I am appreciate any help provided! thanks!

Comment: NSJSONSerialization errored out for some reason and returned nil.  You need to tolerate the nil (skip the `as NSDictionary`, I believe, and maybe add a `?` or some such -- I'm not a Swiftie) and display the `error` value.

Comment: thx Hot Licks , I see what happens , I have some echo as comment on other php file which been involved with , and it return the comment with the value together , then the json parser sucks ..

Answer (score 0):

well I solved this , after spend hours and hours check my back end , it proved again it will be great harmful if you don't have any debug experiences .
I found I echo some comments on other php files , ant it return with JSON together , thus the JSON parser cannot recognise my comment message , then everything hangs .